# Why is my datediff formula not working?

Tags: reporting-services

Good day,

I'm trying to get the difference of months between two different fields. I understand that the "datediff" function should meet my needs. However I am receiving an error. Is my syntax incorrect?

=datediff("mm", Fields!MaturityDate.Value, Fields!DateLastActive.Value)

Thank you!

Comment: @BishNaboB answer should work, but I think you only need 1 `"m"` in the `DateDiff` function to work. `=datediff("m", Fields!MaturityDate.Value, Fields!DateLastActive.Value)`

Answer (score 0):

Use `datediff(DateInterval.Month, Fields!MaturityDate.Value, Fields!DateLastActive.Value)` instead.